# symbol hash could not be resolved

Tags: c++, hash, std

I have such class

```
#ifndef _OBJECT_H_
#define _OBJECT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

namespace core {

class Object {
protected:
    template <>
    struct std::hash<core::Object>
    {
        size_t operator()(const core::Object &x) const = 0;
    };
public:
    virtual Object* clone() = 0;
    virtual int hashCode() = 0;
    virtual std::string getClass() = 0;
    virtual ~Object();
};

}


#endif
```

I want to force all inherited classes to implemented `hash` calculation and provide ability to get `hashcode` using implemented method for overriding `()` in `hash` struct.

However my compiler shows `Symbol 'hash' could not be resolved` error.
I am using `Eclipse c++` with `CDT` plugin and `TDM gcc 5.1.0`. What's the problem?

Comment: By the way, you should not scope your template argument as `core::Object`, just `Object` because it is already in the `core` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an explicit specialization to `std::hash` for `Object`, the correct way to do it is this:

```
namespace core {
    class Object { ... };
}

namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<core::Object> {
        size_t operator()(const core::Object& x) const {
            return x.hashCode(); // though to make this work,
                                 // hashCode() should be const
        }
    };
}
```

The explicit specialization must be in namespace scope - in `std`'s scope, specifically. And you can only make `virtual` functions pure (`= 0`), this one shouldn't be virtual or pure.

Side-note, your `_OBJECT_H` include guard is a [reserved identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/2069064). You should choose another one.

Comment: @user1432980 Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: in g++ settings in `eclipse` it's set to `-std=c++1y`

Comment: Have you #included <functional> where the std::hash template is defined?